# ubuntu xenial64 box password?

Tags: 16.04, vagrant

Probably a stupid question but

I have used the trusty64 box before with vagrant and was trying the xenial64 box but it doesn't accept the usual user: vagrant password: vagrant login?

Comment: It's a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1569237

Comment: So what is the new user then? user: ubuntu password: ???

Comment: If you read the comments you'll know as much as I do.

Comment: Anybody know the f***ing password for ubuntu user?

Comment: Short comment, because no accepted answer yet... You can find the PASS in the: `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-xenial64/20170311.0.0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile`, where "20170311.0.0" should be different directory name... so go to `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/` and find your box and vagrant file.

Comment: I switched to the `bento/ubuntu-16.04` box and it solved a slew of problems.

Comment: I can not believe it's taken me 2 days to get to the bottom of this. I have tried so many different things!

Comment: They fixed it al last https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1569237/comments/111

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As mention by user @prometee in this launchpad discussion [#1569237](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1569237), you can find the password in:

```
~/.vagrant.d/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-xenial64/20161221.0.0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile
```

or:

```
~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-xenial64/20161221.0.0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile
```

depending on your version of Vagrant. (Note the `20161221.0.0` part of the path will vary depending on when the box was downloaded. Also, there might be more than one in your directory.)

Here is mine (line 8):

```
# Front load the includes
include_vagrantfile = File.expand_path("../include/_Vagrantfile", __FILE__)
load include_vagrantfile if File.exist?(include_vagrantfile)

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.base_mac = "022999D56C03"
  config.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
  config.ssh.password = "fbcd1ed4fe8c83b157dc6e0f"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uart1", "0x3F8", "4" ]
     vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "file", File.join(Dir.pwd, "ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log") ]
  end
end
```

FYI, user @racb mention in the same discusison that the `this bug report having been filed` [to ubuntu](https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2016/07/06/%23ubuntu-devel.html#t12:30) and so far `no [...] decision has been made yet` about it.

Comment: There is no file at that location for me

Comment: I found it at ~\.vagrant.d\boxes\ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-xenial64\20170331.0.0\virtualbox\Vagrantfile (in Windows)

Comment: Worked perfectly. My path was `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-xenial64/20170317.0.0/virtualbox` but got the idea where to look for the password.

Comment: This answer must be the accepted answer!

Comment: -Is it safe to change the username and password to "vagrant:vagrant" there?- **Update**: Nope; vagrant reload will ask for a password for vagrant@127.0.0.1 and will not accept the value you used there.

Answer (score 11):

I banged my head against the wall for half a day yesterday until I realised I was running an old version of Virtualbox (5.0.x) and Vagrant (1.8.0)

Updated to VirtualBox 5.1.x and Vagrant 1.8.7 and got better results

Basically the `ubuntu/xenial32` and `ubuntu/xenial64` images are flawed as they don't come with the `vagrant` user out of the box.

This is against the Vagrant [specifications](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base.html)

I ended up using `v0rtex/xenial64` as recommended in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1569237). Not sure why `canonical` is not fixing this

My vagrant file is as follows

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "v0rtex/xenial64"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.10.10.10"

  config.ssh.username = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
     vb.name = "supercool"
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "768"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  end

end
```

If you still want to use the `canonical` provided images it is possible using the following approach

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.10.10.10"

  config.ssh.insert_key = true
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
     vb.name = "supercool"
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "768"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
  end

end
```

If you do that the `/vagrant` folder will be owned by `ubuntu:ubuntu` instead of `vagrant:vagrant`. If you have scripts relying on the `vagrant` user to be there they will break

Answer (score 4):

It has been fixed at last (2018/01/13): https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1569237/comments/111

You may want to run `vagrant box update` and then `vagrant destroy`.

Comment: You can also add this to your Vagrant file:

  config.vm.box_check_update = true
  config.vm.box_version = "20180112.0.0"

Answer (score 3):

A way is to install expect and initiate a password change.
The example below sets the password ubuntu to user ubuntu.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    apt-get install -y expect
    echo '#!/usr/bin/expect
      set timeout 20
      spawn sudo passwd ubuntu
      expect "Enter new UNIX password:" {send "ubuntu\\r"}
      expect "Retype new UNIX password:" {send "ubuntu\\r"}
      interact' > change_ubuntu_password
    chmod +x change_ubuntu_password
  ./change_ubuntu_password
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The new `ubuntu/xenial64` image doesn't come with a default username and password. However you can ssh using an ssh-key generated in your vagrant folder.

Let's say your Vagrantfile is at `/vagrant/vm01/Vagrantfile`, the ssh-key would be in `/vagrant/vm01/.vagrant/machines/..../private_key`

You can login to your vagrant vm using this `private_key`. If the guest machine ask for the key's passphrase, just hit `ENTER` (specifying a blank passphrase). For example, on my Mac:

```
ssh -i /vagrant/vm01/.vagrant/..../private_key <your vm ip> <your vm port>
```

If you still want to log in using username and password, after logging in using the private_key, you can add your own user for logging in later:

```
# create a user for log in
sudo useradd yourusername

# specify a password
sudo passwd yourusername
# then type your password when prompted

# add the user to sudo group
sudo adduser yourusername sudo    

# create a home folder for your user
sudo mkdir /home/yourusername

# add a shell command for your user (normally /bin/bash)
sudo vim /etc/passwd
# find yourusername line, and add /bin/bash to the end.
# the end result would look like this:
yourusername:x:1020:1021::/home/yourusername:/bin/bash
```

Now you can ssh using the new username and password.

Answer (score 1):

You can output OpenSSH valid configuration to connect to the machine by typing `vagrant ssh-config` from within your Vagrantfile folder. The output will show you that password authentication is disabled, however you can point to the private key file:

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User ubuntu
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /path/to/project/folder/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Now you can:

```
ssh -i /path/to/project/folder/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key ubuntu@machine-ip
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Vagrant on Windows and image of ubuntu/xenial64; no password is configured for it.

- Default UserName: vagrant
- Default Host: 127.0.0.1:2222
- Default SSH Key: C:/Vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key

You can login to your VM box via this command:

```
 vagrant ssh
```

or with:

```
ssh -i private_key vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in `ubuntu/xenial64` box but any other 16.04 LTS box I used the bento one that works with the usual `vagrant` username and password:

```
config.vm.box = 'bento/ubuntu-16.04'
config.vm.box_version = "201708.22.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

After `vagrant up` to start a virtual machine, you can `vagrant ssh` to login. 
Run `vagrant help` for more information.